# Slf4j vs JCL - Binding method

Tags: logging, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

Could someone explain to me the difference between the discovery & binding methods followed by the slf4j & jcl.

There are just one or two documents available online & I am unable to exactly understand the difference. `Seems like JCL tries to look for implementation during runtime, but so does Slf4j - it tries to look for implementation of StaticLoggerBinder on classpath.`

Slf4j Code:

```
if (loggerFactoryClassLoader == null) {
            paths = ClassLoader.getSystemResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
        } else {
            paths = loggerFactoryClassLoader.getResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
        }
```

What's am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Commons Logging finds its implementation by using the steps documented in the user's guide:

> The default LogFactory implementation uses the following discovery process to determine what type of Log implementation it should use (the process terminates when the first positive match - in order - is found):
>
> 1. Look for a configuration attribute of this factory named org.apache.commons.logging.Log (for backwards compatibility to pre-1.0 versions of this API, an attribute org.apache.commons.logging.log is also consulted).
>      Configuration attributes can be set explicitly by java code, but they are more commonly set by placing a file named commons-logging.properties in the classpath. When such a file exists, every entry in the properties file becomes an "attribute" of the LogFactory. When there is more than one such file in the classpath, releases of commons-logging prior to 1.1 simply use the first one found. From release 1.1, each file may define a priority key, and the file with the highest priority is used (no priority definition implies priority of zero). When multiple files have the same priority, the first one found is used.
>
>    Defining this property in a commons-logging.properties file is the recommended way of explicitly selecting a Log implementation.
> 2. Look for a system property named org.apache.commons.logging.Log (for backwards compatibility to pre-1.0 versions of this API, a system property org.apache.commons.logging.log is also consulted).
> 3. If the Log4J logging system is available in the application class path, use the corresponding wrapper class (Log4JLogger).
> 4. If the application is executing on a JDK 1.4 system, use the corresponding wrapper class (Jdk14Logger).
> 5. Fall back to the default simple logging wrapper (SimpleLog).

The main difference between SLF4J and Commons Logging is that the Commons Logging API is fairly primitive while the SLF4J API is much more flexible.